# Is the stack only preserved above the stack pointer?

Tags: memory, assembly, stack

I sometimes see disassembled programs which have instructions like:

```
mov %eax, -4(%esp)
```

which stores eax to stack at esp-4, without changing esp.

I'd like to know whether in general, you could put data into the stack beyond the stack pointer, and have those data be preserved (not altered unless I do it specifically).

Also, does this depend on which OS I use?

Comment: Depends on OS and calling convention and luck. In 64 bit mode you get a 128 byte red zone if you are using sysv abi so you are allowed to access that much without explicit allocation. On other systems typically all bets are off and you should not access under the stack pointer. It may segfault (if you happen to cross into unmapped memory) or may be clobbered by stuff such as signals.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! So if I just subtract the stack pointer by a big amount, then there would be a big stack space (which may not even have useful data in it) which the OS wouldn't touch?

Comment: In 32-bit Linux code you subtract from _ESP_ the amount of local stack data your function needs - yes. In 64-bit Linux code you can use 128 bytes below the current value of _RSP_ without moving _RSP_  without fear of that data being clobbered as long as your function doesn't call other functions. As Jester pointed out this is called the Red Zone as discussed in the [System V 64-bit ABI in section 3.2.2](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)

Comment: As to how big a chunk you can allocate in one go, or even in total, depends on your environment again. It's generally a bad idea. If you need big chunks of memory use heap.

Comment: Are you sure it is -4(esp) and not -4(ebp) ?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464974/understanding-a-recursive-ia32-assembly-call/29465479#29465479

Comment: @MichaelPetch: There's one case where there's a red zone and dereferencing `%esp` makes sense: the Linux x32 ABI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matters which OS you use, because different OSes have different ABIs.  (See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki if you don't know what that means).

There are two ways I can see that `mov %eax, -4(%esp)` could be sane:

- In the [Linux x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) (long mode with 32bit pointers), where there's a 128B [red zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)) like in the normal x86-64 ABI.  Compilers frequently generate code using the address-size prefix when they can't prove that e.g. `4(%rdi)` would be the same as `4(%edi)` in every case (e.g. wraparound).  Unfortunately gcc 5.3 still uses 32bit addressing for locals on the stack, which could only wrap if `%rsp == 0` (since the ABI requires it to be 16B-aligned).

  **Anyway, `void foo(void) { volatile int x = 10; }` compiles to

  `movl $10, -4(%esp)`** / `ret` with [gcc 5.3 `-O3 -mx32` on the Godbolt Compiler Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-Wall+-Wextra+-std%3Dgnu11+-fverbose-asm+-O3+-mx32+-march%3Dhaswell',source:'void+foo(void)+%7B+volatile+int+x+%3D+10%3B+%7D%0A//+volatile+forces+a+memory+operation,+even+for+a+local%0A%0Aint+bar(int+a)+%7B%0A++volatile+int+x+%3D+a%3B%0A++return+x%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).
- In (kernel) code that runs with interrupts disabled.  Since nothing asynchronous other than DMA can happen, nothing can clobber your stack memory.  (Although x86 has NMIs: Non-maskable interrupts.  Depending on the handler for NMIs, and whether they can be blocked at all, NMIs could clobber memory below the stack pointer, I think.)

  In user-space, your signal handlers aren't the only thing that can asynchronously clobber memory below the stack pointer:

  As Jester points out in comments on dwelch's answer, pages below the stack pointer can be discarded (asynchronously of course), so a process that temporarily uses a lot of stack isn't wasting all those pages forever.  If `%esp` happens to be at a page boundary, `-4(%esp)` is in a different page.   And instead of faulting in a newly-allocated page of stack memory, access to unmapped pages below the stack pointer turn into segfaults on Linux.

---

Unless you have a guarantee otherwise (e.g. the red zone), then **you must assume that everything below `%esp` is scribbled over between every instruction**.  None of the standard 32bit ABIs have a red-zone, and the Windows 64bit ABI also lacks one.  Asynchronous use of the stack (usually by signal handlers in Linux) is a whole-program thing, not something that the compiler could determine just from the current compilation unit (even in cases where the compiler could prove that `-4(%esp)` was in the same page as `(%esp)`).

Note that the Linux x32 ABI is a 64bit ABI for AMD64 aka x86-64, not i386 aka IA32 aka x86-32.  It's much more like the usual AMD64 ABI, since it was designed after.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are saying, but the Linux Kernel itself doesn't honor the red zone (within the kernel). GCC is told to not use it when compiling the kernel itself. So at no point should you expect the red zone to be honored in the Linux Kernel.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: With interrupts disabled, *nothing* asynchronous (other than DMA...) can happen until you re-enable them.  I'm calling "interrupts disabled" a separate case from when you have a red zone.

Comment: As a historical footnote writing below _ESP_ was a bug on GCC 2.96 under some circumstances. One that caught a number of software projects off guard. I believe by the time official 3.0 was released that nasty bug was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

not sure what you mean by above and below since some folks "see" addresses increasing up or increasing down.

But it doesnt matter.  If the stack was initialized at address X and is currently at Y then the data between X and Y must be preserved (one end  not inclusive).  The memory on either side is fair game.

The compiler not the operating system makes this happen, it moves the stack pointer to cover whatever it needs for that function.  And moves it back when done.  Each nested function consuming more and more stack and each return giving a little back.

Comment: Going beyond Y (I assume you mean Y is the stack pointer) definitely depends on the OS. Asynchronous stuff such as signals and interrupts might assume that region is free. Swapping may not preserve it. The memory might not even be allocated yet and the OS may consider that a fault (linux does).

Comment: then a compiler for that target would know that and not attempt to use it.  It is unwise to do so anyway any time you have more than one execution path using those registers (an isr or something more compilicated (operating system).